# Are Cassandra's Super Columns Useful?

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying to figure out if Cassandra's super columns are useful.

If I understand how Cassandra works (which could be wrong), if I want to read or update a super column, I have to read or write everything in the super column. This means I need to write some mapping code between my object(s) and my super column(s).

Wouldn't it be more efficient for me to simply serialize my object into a regular Cassandra column? It sounds to me like that's exactly what Cassandra does with super columns but they require extra steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I want to read or update a super column, I have to read or write everything in the super column

Not quite: supercolumns are *read* as a unit, but subcolumns may be *updated* independently.

So yes, they do have a use, but no, it is not a very common one and in many cases you can indeed just serialize an object into a standard column.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I guess, depending on my update use cases, either solution would work just fine, though I'd rather standardize one way or another.

Comment: jbellis, is there a place in the documentation that you can point me to that covers this topic? I believe you but I'm interested in reading up on it and I originally posted this question as I was never able to find any.